# trouble about get value from selecteditems

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want to get `SelectedItems` values in ListView` but it does not work!

I have no problem when selecting one item but I want to work in extended mode so it shows any of selected items.

my code is :

```
    List<Fnamelist> familylist = new List<Fnamelist>();
    public class Fnamelist
    {

        public Fnamelist(string fname)
        {
            this.Fname = fname;

        }
        private string fname = string.Empty;
        public string Fname
        {
            get { return fname; }
            set { fname = value; }
        }

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

       MessageBox.Show(((Fnamelist)listView1.SelectedItems).Fname.ToString()); 
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        familylist.Add(new Fnamelist("mike"));
        familylist.Add(new Fnamelist("john"));
        familylist.Add(new Fnamelist("melon"));
        familylist.Add(new Fnamelist("bab"));
        listView1.ItemsSource = familylist;
        listView1.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

xaml :

```
    <Button Content="show" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="331,79,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <ListView Height="129" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,23,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Fname}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

when I clicked show button , it gives error :

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection' to type 'Fnamelist'.`

whats the problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in your `button1_Click` event handler is trying to display the `Fname` of a single item, where as `listView1.SelectedItems` is a collection of items.

You can show the first selected item:

```
MessageBox.Show(((Fnamelist)listView1.SelectedItems[0]).Fname);
```

or iterate the selected items collection and do whatever you want inside, for example, `MessageBox`:

```
foreach (var item in listview1.SelectedItems)
{
      string fname = ((Fnamelist)item).Fname;
      MessageBox.Show(fname);
}
```

On a side-note, you can remove the `ToString()` call. It is redundent since `Fname` is already a string.